# A new upper bound for the forward difference quotient of the exponential function at 0

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

i have found a nice inequality for the forward difference quotient of the exponential function at $0:$

$$(*)\:\:\frac{e^{h}-1}{h}-1\lt e-(1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}}\text{ for }1\gt h\gt 0.$$

To the best of my knowledge this cannot be found in the literature, at least I could not encounter a reference. Perhaps someone else can point out an appropriate passage to me?

I have been searching for an estimation like that because together with the lower bound $0\lt\frac{e^{h}-1}{h}-1$ for $h\gt  0$, which is equivalent to the well-known $e\gt(1+h) ^{\frac{1}{h}}$ for $h\gt0$, we can immediately deduce $\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{e^{h}-1}{h}=1$. As for the left-sided limit also $$\lim_{h \to 0^{-}} \frac{e^{h}-1}{h}=\lim_{k \to 0^{+}}\frac{e^{-k}-1}{-k}=\lim_{k \to 0^{+}}(e^{-k}\cdot \frac{1-e^{k}}{-k})=\lim_{k \to 0^{+}}e^{-k}\cdot\lim_{k \to 0^{+}}\frac{e^{k}-1}{k}=1,$$ the derivative of the  exponential function at $0$ has directly (!) been shown to be equal to $1$. This ensures trivially that
$$\frac{d e^{x}}{dx}=e^x\text{ for all }x\in \mathbb{R}$$ using the functional equation of the exponential function.

When I attended the beginners analysis course where this fundamental property of the  exponential function was proved I disliked that a detour via the inverse function $x\mapsto\ln (x)$ was taken and this is done alike in all textbooks I know of.
My question to the reader now is:

> Can you give a proof of inequality (*)?

Of course $\frac{d e^{x}}{dx}=e^{x}$ must not be used, otherwise the reasoning would be circular.

But I am also interested in any proof without this restriction, you may use anything you know about the exponential function. I think this is still a major challenge.

Comment: @Anne Bauval You are right with this, but for  taking the limits in the rest of my reasoning only the range $0\lt h\lt 1$is needed. I actually had intended to claim  (*) for this. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @Anne Bauval I had also responded to your first comment but for some reason I do not know it has disappeared. So I will repeat it here: I consider the exponential function  be be defined in the most elementary way, so for natural exponents it is just a multiple product of the base with itself, then it is extended to rational exponents by taking appropriate roots, and finally to irrational exponents by approximating them by rational ones using the fact that the function on the rationals is uniformly continuous which is easy to prove.

Comment: (Uniformly continuous locally.) This way you define $x\mapsto a^x$ for every $a>0.$ But how do you define $e,$ and how do you prove that $\lim_{h\to0}(1+h)^{1/h}=e$?

Comment: @Anne Bauval Yes, uniformly continuous  on each bounded interval of rational numbers which suffices to define the function for irrational numbers. I define $e:=\lim_{n \to \infty }(1+\frac{1}{n}) ^{n}$ which is the original definition given by Euler. It is not hard to show that this ensues $e=\lim_{h \to 0 }(1+h) ^{\frac{1}{h}} $ but you may as well start from this limit as the definition of $e$. So, how do you now prove (*)?

Comment: (Yes, this is the meaning of local uniform continuity, and it is because it suffices that I mentionned this easy correction.) No idea yet of course, since I was awaiting for these clarifications (btw, I suggest you include them in your post, rather than in comments). But what about *your own* attempt(s)? And wouldn't it be easier to prove $$\forall h\in(0,1),\;\frac{e^h-1}h\le\frac1{1-h}\text{ i.e. }e^h\le\frac1{1-h}$$ (which is weaker than your $(*)$, but sufficient for your purpose)?

Comment: Maybe useful: one can prove, using only (from your definition) the continuity and functional equation of $\exp$, that it is differentiable and $\exp'(x)=e^x\exp'(0).$

Comment: @Anne Bauval Yes, even starting from the elementary definition of the exponential function I have in mind it is standard quite easy stuff (though somewhat tedious) to show the functional equation and based on this the continuity. But I want to make one thing utterly clear here.: I have a strong independent interest in a proof of this marvelous and surprising inequality (*), no matter what it is used for (it really seems to have been unknown). I just did not want to pose this as an isolated problem.

Comment: So I now precisely challenge the reader. Can you give a proof of inequality (*)? You may use anything you know about the exponential function, so its power series, that the derivative equals the function itself, etc. Do not prove any inequality which is weaker than (*) though still suited to prove this latter property. Give a proof of (*9 regardless of the special purpose I have presented as an application. Although"everything is allowed" you will see that it is still a major challenge. Put the problem this way there is no need to change my post.

Comment: I think you should edit your post to 1) make explicit this huge modification of your question. Above all, suppress the final sentence and replace it by "You may use anything you know [etc.]" 2) include your own efforts to answer it.

Comment: @Anne Bauval I have added your suggestion at the end of my post which makes clear my independent interest in a proof of (*).

Comment: @Anne Bauval You asked about my own efforts: Please ses my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

My own  efforts to prove (*) have meanwhile been successful. I can present here an elegant and rather short proof: I apply the mean value theorem of calculus to the function $x\mapsto f(x):=x^{s}$ for any real number $s\gt 1$:

$f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})=(x_{1}-x_{2})\cdot f^{'}(\xi)$, where $\xi$ is a real number between $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$

I use this for the points $x_{1}:= e^{\frac{1}{s}}$ and $x_{2}:= 1+\frac{1}{s}$. Now $e\gt (1+\frac{1}{s})^{s}$ for any $s\gt 1$ ensues $x_{2}\lt x_{1}$ and thus $x_{2}\lt\xi\lt x_{1}$. Because of $f^{'}(\xi)=s\cdot \xi^{s-1}$ the mean value theorem above now takes the following form:

$e-(1+\frac{1}{s})^{s}=(e^{\frac{1}{s}}-(1+\frac{1}{s}))\cdot s\cdot \eta$, where $\eta:=\xi^{s-1}$ satisfies $(1+\frac{1}{s})^{s-1}\lt \eta\lt e^{\frac{s-1}{s}}$

$s\gt 1$ implies $(1+\frac{1}{s})^{s-1}\gt 1$ an thus $\eta\gt 1$.With this the mean value theorem yields the  inequality $e-(1+\frac{1}{s})^{s}\gt (e^{\frac{1}{s}}-(1+\frac{1}{s}))\cdot s=s\cdot (e^{\frac{1}{s}}-1)-1$, which is what is we wanted to show. To see this just substitute $s$ by $\frac{1}{h}$ and mind that $s\gt 1$ is equivalent to $0\lt h\lt 1$.

Comment: +1 but it is more elegant not claiming being elegant ;-)

Comment: @Anne Bauval Indeed ,this was only a .typo which I have corrected meanwhile. The inequality with the reversed comparison sign is what had to be shown.

Comment: Indeed, this is precisely what I wrote in my first (now deleted) comment, before you corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your proof.

Let $a:=(1+h)^{1/h}$ and $b:=$ any number $>a.$ Since $a>1,$ by the mean value theorem,
$$\exists c>1,\quad b^h-a^h=(b-a)h\,c^{h-1}$$
i.e. (since moreover $0<h<1$)
$$b^h-(1+h)<\left(b-(1+h)^{1/h}\right)h,$$
which, for $b=e,$ is what had to be shown.

Comment: It is indeed the same idea. What makes it a bit shorter is that you directly argue with the variable $h$ instead of the unnecessary detour via the variable $s$. Wat I find more interesting than this slight simplification is that your reasoning clearly points out that the inequality remains valid if the Euler number $e$ is replaced by any number $b\gt e$. I had also noticed this from the fact that  the only property of $e$ which is used in my proof is $e\gt (1+\frac{1}{s})^{s}$ for all $s\gt  1$, so the proof still works for any number with this property.

Comment: Yes, I know all this and I wrote the answer so as to make it obvious. And it is *much* shorter and simpler, rather than "a bit" or "slightly" ;-)